# Can somebody get Firebase credentials from my apk and use them?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Can somebody else get the Firebase credentials from my APK and use them? Is this prevented by adding the SHA-1 keys for Android?

If it is prevented, what do I need security rules for since only code from my app with my SHA-1 can manipulate database at all?

If it is not prevented, can somebody else use my Firebase database as long as his requests fit the security rules? (Write 2nd client, which actually cannot do bad things but should not be allowed at all.)

Im not sure how I should think about security rules:

A) Protecting data against access and manipulation from bad guys + B?

B) Just a set of rules to keep data in a certain state and prevent my software from doing invalid database request?

Answer (score 2):

A Firebase Database can be accessed via the REST API, or any of the client libraries. The decision about whether a client can or can't do something is entirely based on the rules.

You can even just access the Database URL in a web browser and see a JSON response by putting `.json` on the end, e.g. https://[YOUR_PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/.json

So the answer is definitely B! The default rules in a new Firebase project are that read and write to the database require auth, but you can configure them to provide whatever levels of protection you need.

Take a look at the [Database Rules quickstart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart) to see what you can do!

Answer (score 1):

We don't ship the Realtime Database secret (or any other "secret" material) in the json file that gets baked into your app. That file simply contains resource identifiers that allow us to know which resources (database, storage bucket, analytics, etc.) to properly authenticate to (we use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) for these purposes), and we handle server side authorization to ensure that users are properly logged in.

If you are authorizing your requests properly (using [Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), for instance), your data is secure!

I'd recommend watching [The Key to Firebase Security](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI), one of our I/O talks, which talks in greater detail about how this works.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Thanks to the new feature called [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check), it is now actually possible to limit calls to your Realtime Database to only those coming from iOS, Android and Web apps that are registered in your Firebase project.

You'll typically want to combine this with the user authentication based security that Mike and Ian describe in their answers, so that you have another shield against abusive users that *do* use your app.